# Is there a better way to pass props to a component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props

This is my main app.js file --- I'm trying to pass down the state values and functions defined here as props to my child components through react-router-dom:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class BooksApp extends Component {

  state = {
    bookRepository: [{tuna: 'sandwhich'}],
    searchResults: [],
    featuredBook: {}
  }

  fixer = (someBooks, type) => { //code }

  async updateBookRepository(bookID, shelfID) { //code }

  async updateSearchResults(userQuery) { // code }

  async updateFeaturedBook(bookID, shelfID) {//code }


  render() {

    const myProps = {
      bookRepository:this.state.bookRepository,
      searchResults:this.state.searchResults,
      featuredBook:this.state.featuredBook, 
      updateBookRepository:this.updateBookRepository, 
      updateSearchResults:this.updateSearchResults, 
      updateFeaturedBook:this.updateFeaturedBook
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => (
          <Bookshelves {...props} {...myProps} />
        )}/>

        <Route path='/search' render={(props) => (
          <Searchpage {...props}  {...myProps}/>
        )}/>

        <Route path='/featuredBook/:bookID' render={(props) => (
          <Featuredbook {...props}  {...myProps}/>
        )}/>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm accessing the props like so:

```
class Bookshelves extends Component {

  state = {
      shelves: ['currentlyReading', 'wantToRead', 'read']
    }

  render() {

    const { bookRepository } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
      The props are: {console.log(this.props)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And this works, and they show all show up under my props when I attempt to access them, but I'm having trouble udnerstanding WHY I need to define my own object and then pass that down to my child components.

Is there some way that I can assign them to the `props`-ish object itself so that...

```
<Route exact path='/' render={(props) => (
  <Bookshelves {...props} />
}/>
```

...would pass them down?

Comment: Hmm. I think this is how you have to do it with react-router. I ended up using a similar structure. I think each `Route` gets the location/history/etc props via the `props` argument, but that does not include the props of the component that the `Route` is being rendered in, so you have to add those as well.

Comment: If that's just the way react-router works, then I'm cool with that. I just didn't see anything about it in their online documentation, and I wanted to be sure I wasn't "not-understanding" some aspect of props/components in React.

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure everything in one line

```
<Route exact path='/' render={(props) => (
  <Bookshelves {...props, ...this.state} />
)}/>
```

Comment: That does work for the `state` values that I want to pass, but not for the functions. I attempted this during my trial-and-error phase of the project. :)

Comment: If you `bind` the methods, you'll be able to pass them down without having `this` context issues. Are you trying to pass all functions down without specifying them explicitely?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to pass them all down without specifying them explicitly. Would binding them somehow attach them to the main props object so they'd get passed down with `{...props}` instead of via my explicitly defined `{...myProps}` object?

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't do that. The Component receiving the props should know what props are being passed to it and the props should be validated with `prop-types`. Although you can try destructuring the entire `this` object into the props to achieve what you want.`{...props, ...this.state, ...this}`. You should `bind` the methods in your parent component first before passing them down. Pl note that this is not a recommended approach.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice --- I tried binding the functions, and they still didn't show up in my `{...props}` pass. :\ I think passing in my own props object is just a fact-of-life with react-router.

I have a question though: if I declare my functions with the arrow function syntax, doesn't that close a lexical scope around the component that they are declared in? Same as a `.bind(this)` would've done?

Comment: If you declare your functions with the arrow syntax, yes, you wouldn't need to bind. But in React world, when you declare a function with arrow, they won't be in the prototype but rather get defined inside the constructor (that's how babel transpiles it). This usually makes it difficult to test class functions. That's why the recommeded approach is to not use arrow functions in a component if you need to better test your component. Of course this doesn't matter if you're not bothered about testing the function.